# Why can LEFT OUTER JOIN fail to work?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Samples
```

return `628`.

While the following query

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (

    SELECT
    sa.*, 
    tagLists.tagNames AS tagNames,
    tagLists.ProjectID AS ProjectID
      FROM Samples sa
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TagLists tagLists
          ON sa.spotID = tagLists.taggedItemID
          AND 6 = tagLists.taggedItemType
  ) ex

  WHERE ex.ProjectID IS NULL
```

returns empty table.

In other words, outer join query

```
SELECT
        sa.*, 
        tagLists.tagNames AS tagNames,
        tagLists.ProjectID AS ProjectID
          FROM Samples sa
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TagLists tagLists
              ON sa.spotID = tagLists.taggedItemID
              AND 6 = tagLists.taggedItemType
```

contains no any row with `ProjectID` is null.

Why? Doesn't `LEFT OUTER JOIN` guarantee that all rows from left table should present?

**UPDATE**

<s>Sorry, of course there is no not-null joined rows actually in `tagLists`.</s>

**UPDATE 2**

Sorry guys I am a fool: there were really non-null rows I was not care about...

Comment: You didn't show us any data, making this comment speculative, but if every record in `Samples` matches to a record in `TagLists`, then `ex.ProjectID` will never be `NULL`, which would give your current result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only situation when your query would return no data is when every row of `Samples` has a corresponding row in `TagLists` satisfying the join condition, with all such rows having non-NULL value in the `ProjectID` field. In other words, every sample has a tag list item of type six.

A good way to test this would be removing the `WHERE` clause, and verifying that all 628 rows returned a valid `ProjectID`.

Comment: This sounds a lot like my comment.  How about giving that comment an upvote?